What is choice between node drain versus role switching in WSFC FCI patching?
I'm learning about patching OS and SQL FCI.
I have a 2 node SQL FCI (active/passive). The SQL service exists on both nodes, but is running only on the active node. This is managed by the WSFC.
I also understand that it is recommended to start patching the passive node first, then failover, and then patch the other now passive node.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/draining-nodes-for-planned-maintenance-with-windows-server-2012/ba-p/371713
This document suggests to drain the node prior to patching.
I want to ask if this process (node drain) should be followed for both the OS and SQL patching? The reason for asking is that I can see in the WSFC failover cluster manager that the passive node doesn't own any role ownership. Only the active node owns the role. So what would be the purpose of doing node drain on the passive node?
After patching passive node, when I then want to perform failover of the active node, then do I do node drain on active node (so that it fails-over to passive node) OR do I right click on role -> more actions -> move resource -> select the other node ?

For SQL maintenance it's not necessary to pause any cluster nodes.  You might have other cluster workloads (hopefully just other SQL FCIs).
But if the FCI is your only workload pausing each node for maintenance  gives you a uniform procedure for SQL and OS updates.

As per documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/upgrade-a-sql-server-failover-cluster-instance?view=sql-server-ver16#perform-a-rolling-upgrade-or-update, the node being patched is automatically removed from possible owner list and hence there is no chance of failover to it when it is being patched. So what would be the purpose of pausing a node?

My testing shows that the node being patched still participated in failover. That is - it is not auto removed from the possible owner list. And the disks get attached to the passive node when I kill the active node while the passive node is getting patched. So should I manually remove node2 from the possible owner list? If so then where exactly do I need to make this change? Do I need to do this on all the disks, or cluster, or FCI, or SQL/agent service or all of these?
